# Write to yaml file with specific format

Tags: python, yaml

I have the following yaml

```
---  
- - :whitelist
  - MIT
  - :who: 
    :why: 
    :when: 2015-10-14 11:59:36.990687307 Z
```

Reading this yaml file with

```
import yaml
items = None
with open('yaml_file.yml') as yaml_file:
    items = yaml.load(yaml_file):
```

gives me a list of items like this:

```
[':whitelist', 'MIT', {':who': None, ':why': None, ':when': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 14, 11, 59, 36, 990687)}]
```

but trying to do the oposite:

```
data = [':whitelist', 'MIT', {':who': None, ':why': None, ':when': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 14, 11, 59, 36, 990687)}]
with open('yaml_file.yml', 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml.dump(data, yaml_file, default_flow_style=False)
```

gives me this format

```
- :whitelist
- MIT
- :when: 2015-10-14 11:59:36.990687
  :who: null
  :why: null
```

How can I achieve the same format on the yaml file and also represent None as empty strings when dumping my dictionary?

Comment: The YAML specification does not require an implementation to give you this level of control over the presentation format, and I don't believe PyYaml supports it.

Comment: So you mean I should implement something like this my self

Comment: Absolutely not. Implementing YAML is not easy. I rather suggest that if you want that level of control, YAML might not be the correct tool for you.